# ¿Porqué siempre me devuelve 0s el programa?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo unas medidas para ver cuanto tarda la máquina en ejecutar ciertos algoritmos de ordenación. Aquí está el código donde estoy calculando dicho tiempo

```
void imprimirAnalisisPromedioOrdenacion(){
    const unsigned N = 20;
    int vec[N];
    int n = 1000;

    // inicialización del vector con las condiciones propuestas
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        vec[i] = n;
        n += 1000;
    }

    // permuta aleatoria
    random_shuffle(vec, vec+N);

    cronometro crono;
    crono.activar();
    // Descomentar en funcion al algoritmo a probar
    //intercambioDirecto(vec, N);
    seleccionDirecta(vec, N);
    //insercionDirecta(vec, N);
    crono.parar();

    cout << "El tiempo en ejecutar el algoritmo ha sido " << crono.tiempo() << "s." << endl;
}
```

El caso es que siempre devuelve cero y ya no sé que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias por su ayuda. Las función selección directa y la clase cronómetro están bien implementadas.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema de resolución y de cantidad de datos. fíjate que este código:

```
for (int i = 10; i != 1000000; i *= 10)
{
    int *datos = new int[i];

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 dev{rd()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> d{0u, ~unsigned{}};

    std::generate(datos, datos + i, [&] { return d(dev); });

    {
        auto ini = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::sort(datos, datos + i);
        auto fin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto tiempo = fin - ini;
        std::cout << "Ordenar " << i << " numeros = "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tiempo).count() << " milisegundos.\n";
    }

    delete []datos;
}
```

Produce la siguiente [salida](https://tio.run/##lZLPbtswDMbP8VNwGTDYXdKm2GGo7eUV9gBZEGgS6xCTqUB/2kPgvXpGyUu3YKf5Yusj@fFHyvp0WmureLhc3hNrmwxCr4/esdtWfxSv2Ljxb4VciB7Vjabs4DzFo4gVcYRREddNda4Wz85DnSWCL/C46eT9Ln@UJ5/u8qmpFpK7yHl3RkUXJJnxFUTY0b6rJBaiaduZ5mDwhTSCN901MMbHp6dPn0EiZ2/qZnqLJCZhGA9idTAk6PQ9RXLcJw40MJotmPMmreDnVThPUg3yXC0GZPQqYl3QVjATfgRawe7DHs7gMSbPYGpp33QwNYU4T7RQKToZI09fvOYNt@2RhuPBY3C20By0dfpH27J7rZvMPncOzsd/us7xYvxM/N/GpTASjicntdlhnQE7eHjQyupkZdK8ePQvyq4lc0RAq04BzRuXdilC38PyqzfIysMyn6hIwGlEX65wmQsWIt4QmiTLLGgqxP4mNJK1FFA7NmFbz5DNvXTjWDezu6RIxpDkRwj333iZZ5ryug1aFPLdvixK5Kz@vplNV02Xyy8):

```
Ordenar 10 numeros = 0 milisegundos.
Ordenar 100 numeros = 0 milisegundos.
Ordenar 1000 numeros = 0 milisegundos.
Ordenar 10000 numeros = 1 milisegundos.
Ordenar 100000 numeros = 19 milisegundos.
```

No tenemos información relevante hasta intentar ordenar diez mil números. Si [cambiamos la resolución de la medida de tiempo a microsegundos](https://tio.run/##lZLPbtswDMbP9lOwGTDYXdKm2GGo7eUV9gBZYKgS6wiVqUB/2oPhvXpGyU23YKf5Yusj@fFHyvJ02kgjaDifP2mSJiqETh6dJbsr/yhOkLLj34q2PjgUV5owg3U6HFksNQUYhaaqLqeyeLYOqiRp@A4P25bfN@kjP@l0m051WXBukfJulQjWczLhG7Cw14e25JgPqmkWml7hq5YITrWXwBgeHh@/fgOOTE5V9fwRiaSZYezZqlea0fVTDNpSF8nrgVDtQE3buIZfF2GauRr4uVgMSOhEwCqjrWEh/AJ6DfvPB5jAYYiOQFXcvm5hrjNxmqgQMVgeI02fvZYNN81RD8feobcm0/TSWPnSNGTfqjqxL529deGfrks8Gz9r@m/jXBg0jifLtclhkwBbuL@XwshoeNK0eHSvwmw4c0RAI04e1QeXtDFA18Hqh1NIwsEqnXSWgOKILl/hKhUULF4RqsjLzGjCh@4qNGrJlSgtKb@rFsj6jrtRqOrF/T1liPwn@LuftEpDzWnfCg0y@v6QN8VyUt@vZtuW8/n8Gw) obtenemos:

```
Ordenar 10 numeros = 1 microsegundos.
Ordenar 100 numeros = 9 microsegundos.
Ordenar 1000 numeros = 121 microsegundos.
Ordenar 10000 numeros = 1606 microsegundos.
Ordenar 100000 numeros = 19300 microsegundos.
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la clase `cronometro` realmente funciona bien, ten en cuenta que los procesadores actuales pueden ejecutar millones de instrucciones por segundo.

Ese código podría ejecutarse en mucho menos de 1s teniendo en cuenta que N=20. Tranquilamente podría tomar algunos microsegundos.

Si la resolución del cronómetro es menor que ese tiempo, obtienes 0. En ese sentido, también es posible que el valor sea tan pequeño y esté siendo redondeado a la hora de imprimirlo.

Puedes asegurarte que el cronómetro funciona bien con la función [`sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) y un número de segundos.

```
this_thread::sleep_for(3);
cout << crono.tiempo();
```

Si el cronómetro funciona bien, debería imprimir 3 aproximadamente. Sino tendrás que cambiar la implementación. Sugiero la librería [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).

Si el problema es el redondeo, puedes aumentar el número de decimales que se imprimen con [`setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) o [`precision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision). Así:

```
cout << setprecision(nueva_precision);

cout.precision(nueva_precision);
```